# CSS parameter scaling based on screen size

Tags: css, viewport

Is there an automated way to scale height and width of elements defined in CSS based on screen sizes?
These days there are so many different screen sizes in the market, it is quite onerous to create separate CSS for each.  Wondering if a same CSS can be used with an automatic scaling based on screen size.  Say for example, the original CSS is built for 1200x800 screen size.  If the page is opened on an screen half of this size, all css element in which height and width is defined in pixels, should automatically reduce to half. I understand it will not look good when the page is opened in a very small screen because everything will look tiny.  However, the requirement basically is to automatically adjust the app screen to laptop, desktop and tablet screens.

For example, I have a div and inside that div there are 5 buttons (created using CSS).  On smaller screens the button row wraps into two lines making it look very bad.  This is just an example.  Most other screen elements behave similarly.

Comment: You have multiple approaches available, among them media-queries (million links around but here's one : http://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/) and another one I like a lot, viewport units (see here for example : http://css-tricks.com/the-lengths-of-css/ Viewport Percentage Lengths). You are basically describing what is called Responsive Design (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) --- Have Fun ^^

Comment: Thanks! vw and vh sound interesting. I am looking into it. Only issue I see upfront it that older versions of browsers do not support these. Based on our Web Master analytic, there are so many people still using 5 year old browser versions.

Comment: Maybe try this then (just did a quick search for responsive design without css 3 on Google :) ) : http://responsejs.com/

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to right direction. I just made one small change in CSS. Instead of using font in px, I changed it to rem (there are a lot of ul/li menu buttons that takes H/W from the font of the caption inside). This alone has made a tremendous difference on cross viewport rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented and approved by OP :

You have multiple approaches available, among them media-queries (million links around but here's one : http://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries) and another one I like a lot, viewport units (see here for example : http://css-tricks.com/the-lengths-of-css Viewport Percentage Lengths). You are basically describing what is called Responsive Design (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) --- Have Fun ^^

Maybe try this for responsive design without css 3 : http://responsejs.com

Answer (score 2):

Media-queries are the way to go. As for the old browsers(IE <10), this is a great webpage with "polyfills" for those:

https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills